# how to divide two columns from two different text files in bash

Tags: shell-script

I have two text files each contains a column of numbers.
How can I divide this two columns element vise and save the new column in a new text file? I tried this but it didn't work.

```
declare -a col1
declare -a col2
col1=`awk '{print $1}' File1.txt`
col2=`awk '{print $1}' File2.txt`
awk '{print $File1/$File2} > File3.txt
```

Comment: Are you looking for `paste`?  `paste File1.txt File2.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean by divide is the mathematical division operation, then try this:

```
paste inf1 inf2 | awk '{print($1/$2)}'
```

That's assuming that `inf1` and `inf2` are two files with **one** column of numbers, something like:

```
$ seq 10 30 > inf1
$ seq  2 22 > inf2
$ paste inf1 inf2 | awk '{print($1/$2)}'
5
3.66667
3
2.6
2.33333
2.14286
2
1.88889
1.8
1.72727
1.66667
1.61538
1.57143
1.53333
1.5
1.47059
1.44444
1.42105
1.4
1.38095
1.36364
```

If you need an specific format then use `printf` instead of `print`.

If it **must** be done in a shell (bash code, could be converted if needed):

```
$ readarray -t a <inf1
$ readarray -t b <inf2
$ for ((i=0;i<${#a[@]};i++)); do
      printf '%8.4f\n' "$((10000000*a[i]/b[i]))e-7"
done
  5.0000
  3.6667
  3.0000
  2.6000
  2.3333
  2.1429
  2.0000
  1.8889
  1.8000
  1.7273
  1.6667
  1.6154
  1.5714
  1.5333
  1.5000
  1.4706
  1.4444
  1.4211
  1.4000
  1.3810
  1.3636
```

Answer (score 0):

dc is a good tool for this job :

```
dc -f File1.txt -f File2.txt -e '5kzdsa2/sb[la:zla1-dsa0<m]smlmx[la1+ddsa;zrlb+;z/pclbla<n]snlnx' > File3.txt
```

and with comment :

```
dc -f File1.txt -f File2.txt -e '
# set the precision
5k
# keep the number of item in register a and the half in register b
z d sa 2 / sb
# populate indexed register z from z[1] to z[number of item]
[la :z la 1 - d sa 0  <m]sm lmx
# get 2 items from register z and divide them 
[ la 1 + d d sa ;z r lb + ;z / p c lb la <n ]sn lnx' > File3.txt
```

Comment: Tell your cat to stop walking over your keyboard!  ;-)